# Variadic Functions - Is there an argument limit?

Tags: c

An interesting question came up that I've done a bit of research on but cannot find a conclusive answer.  I also have a suspicion as to the answer but I thought the SO crowd might actually *know*.

**Is there actually a limit to the number of arguments passed to a variadic function?**

All of the documentation that I can find is completely silent on this point.  There are minimum numbers for supported arguments in the various C standards, but no maximum listed.  I have already tested code with north of 60,000 arguments with no trouble at all.

**My Hypothesis**

I suspect that this is actually architecture dependent and would effectively be limited by the maximum stack size.

**Edit**

I may have sent people haring off in the wrong direction.  My focus is not on the *minimum* but on whether or not they are aware of any actual *maximum*, whether that is based on a standard, compiler implementation or architecture.

Comment: Why would the C standard define a maximum?

Comment: The C standard does not require more than 127 arguments to be supported for any function call (C2011 5.2.4.1).  Conforming implementations may support more, and it may be easier for them to do so with a variadic function, but for maximum portability you should not use more than 127.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Limiting yourself to 127 arguments doesn't really help portability. A conforming compiler needn't support 127 arguments for *all* function calls, only for one call in one specific program -- and that call needn't be to a variadic function.

Comment: I've amended to refocus the question.  It's not really about a minimum.  It's about a maximum.

Comment: @KeithThompson While the standard allows that just one call could use the full 127 arguments, it would be incredibly perverse for an implementation to be so specific in its limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such limit is imposed by the C standard.

The C standard does require any conforming implementation to support *some* program that passes at least 127 arguments in a function call (see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 5.2.4.1), but that's neither an upper nor a lower bound for variadic functions; the call needn't be to a variadic function, and implementations are free to support more than 127 arguments. The section that defines `<stdarg.h>`, 7.16, doesn't mention any limits.

In practice, any limit is likely to be imposed by available resources, either at compile time (when compiling the call) or at run time (when executing it).

And simply due to common sense and market forces, compilers are likely to support arbitrarily long argument lists rather than imposing some fixed limit. Once you're required to support 127 arguments, it's probably easier to allocate any needed data structures dynamically than to use fixed-size structures. (The point of the translation limits in 5.2.4.1 is, in my opinion, to encourage compilers not to impose fixed limits at all.)

On the other hand, a conforming compiler *could* impose an unreasonable small limit, and a compiler for a very small embedded system might even have a valid reason to do so.

Comment: The unreasonably low number of arguments, I suspect, is why the C standard sets the minimum at 127.  Your answer, otherwise, seems to agree with my suspicions.

Comment: Many architectures impose limits on stack frame sizes, and arguments are usually passed on the stack.